# What is the difference between toolbar ,collapsing toolbar ,app bar ,bottom navigation bar and action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What is the difference between these Android components?

- Action Bar
- Toolbar
- Collapsing Toolbar
- Bottom navigation bar
- App Bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Action bar,App bar,Toolbar** all are same.In this bar,We can add(or hide) up arrow to go to previous activity.we can add overflow menu also set page title with in this bar.

**Support action bar** is also toolbar but it is more flexible than classic tool bar.below image is toolbar.

[image]

**Collapsing Toolbar** is also toolbar, will shrink and expand when you scroll.

[image]

**Bottom navigation bar** contains icon each icon will bring us to different fragment.Activity that holds this bar will be the container for all fragment.below is bottom navigation bar.

[image]